# Identifying the lowest value in a row in Microsoft Excel after VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I'm trying to achieve the following in Excel: I have two worksheets with details of students and their marks for three different subjects.

**Worksheet 1** has a **Student Name** column with names of all students in the class and a **Subject** column that tells which subject they have scored the least in.

**Worksheet 2** has the same **Student Name** column but the rows may not be in the same order. **Worksheet 2** has three more columns named **English, Maths and Science** populated with the marks scored by the students.

The **Subject** column for each student in **Worksheet 1** should look up the **Student Name** column in **Worksheet 2** for the corresponding student name and then from that row identify the lowest value and return the subject name (which is the first value in the column/table header of the lowest value). I was thinking of using the VLOOKUP function but I'm not sure how I can nest another function within it to search for the lowest value in the row and return the subject name/table header value.

[image: Worksheet 1]

[image: Worksheet 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(_marks,INDEX($E$2:$G$10,MATCH($A2,$D$2:$D$10,0),0),
FILTER($E$1:$G$1,MIN(_marks)=_marks))
```

---

Edit:

When a student scores same minimum marks for two subjects. Then we can use as below to return both the subjects,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(_marks,INDEX($E$2:$G$10,MATCH($A2,$D$2:$D$10,0),0),
ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER($E$1:$G$1,MIN(_marks)=_marks)))
```

---

Comment: Hi Mayukh,
Thank you very much, it works! Just a quick question though. When a student scores the same minimum marks for two subjects, excel is giving me a #SPILL value in the cell. Is there any way we can handle this error to return both subjects or at least one of them?

Comment: @BigArcade I have updated please refer above.

Comment: @BigArcade or to take one of them you can use `=LET(_marks,INDEX($E$2:$G$10,MATCH($A2,$D$2:$D$10,0),0),
CHOOSECOLS(FILTER($E$1:$G$1,MIN(_marks)=_marks),1))`

Comment: Everything works perfectly. Thanks champ!